# AngularFire FirebaseError: "No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app)."

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I updated Node modules `rxfire` from 6.0.3 to 6.0.4 and `firebase` from 9.23.0 to 10.3.0. Now my Angular app won't start. I ran `npm install rxfire@6.0.3` and `npm install firebase@9.23.0` to revert back to the old Node modules but the error persists. I also deleted my node modules and ran `npm install`.

The error is:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
```

Several StackOverflow pages answer this question for namespaced Firebase, not for modularized Firebase.

Here's my `app.module.ts` file:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...import lots more modules...
// AngularFire modules
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideAnalytics, getAnalytics, ScreenTrackingService, UserTrackingService } from '@angular/fire/analytics';
import { provideAuth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore, getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideFunctions, getFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { providePerformance, getPerformance } from '@angular/fire/performance';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...lots of components...
  ],
  imports: [
    // Firebase modules
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideFunctions(() => getFunctions()),
    providePerformance(() => getPerformance()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),
    // Angular modules
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ...lots more modules...
  ],
  providers: [
   ...a few services...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The error is saying that I need to put `initializeApp(environment.firebase))` above everything else. It is at the top of the `imports`.

The error is also saying that it's trying to hook up to a Firebase App called `[DEFAULT]`. My Firebase project is called `LanguageTwo`. What is a "Firebase App"? Is that the same as a Firebase project?

I have

- Angular 16.2.1 and 16.2.2
- @angular/fire@7.6.1
- firebase@10.3.0
- firebase-admin@11.10.1
- rxfire@6.0.4
- rxjs@7.8.1
- typescript@5.1.6

Maybe the update this morning updated a dependency that's causing the trouble?

I reverted back to

- firebase@9.23.0
- rxfire@6.0.3

deleted the npm modules folder and ran `npm install.` Same error message.

I ran `ng add @angular/fire` again to connect the Angular app to my Firebase project and app.

Comment: Do you have `firebase` property in your `environment.ts`?

Comment: Yes, I have the `firebase` config object in my `environment.ts`.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue I have the same, just after adding couple new components to NGModules

Answer (score 1):

`initializeApp` doesn't have to be at the top of the imports, it just has to be above the rest of your other firebase `provide` calls. You can't `getAuth` `getFirestore` or `getAnalytics` unless you have first provided the firebase app itself. So your imports look good in that regard, however the only thing else that I can think is that you have not actually created the firebase application through the firebase console? Are you accepting connections to it? Did you maybe switch some of the firebase config values?

Comment: The Firestore database is in the console. I didn't change any code, I just switched on the computer, updated node modules, and it's not working. I'm going to try to replicate the error from a new Angular build, without any of my code.

Answer (score 1):

This morning I switched on my computer and my app opened! This is with `firebase` 9.2.3 and `rxfire` 6.0.3.

I'm not going to update `firebase` and `rxfire` until new versions of each are released.

UPDATE: `firebase 10.3.1` and `rxfire 6.0.5` were released this morning. I updated, and got `No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created` error message.

I reverted back to `firebase 9.2.3` and `rxfire 6.0.3`. The error persisted. I restarted my laptop, ran `firebase init` again. Nothing worked.

Then I built a new Angular app from scratch. I set `firebase 9.2.3` and `rxfire 6.0.3` in `package.json`. The Angular test screen opened. Then I copied my `src` folder from my (non-functioning) Angular app to the new Angular app. My app opened and runs normally.

To summarize, updating to `rxfire 6.0.4` or `6.0.5` makes my Angular app crash. You need `6.0.4` or later to use Firebase 10. Reinstalling `rxfire 6.0.3` doesn't fix the problem.

UPDATE: I used `nvm` to switch from `node 20.6.1` to `node 18.17.1`. Same error message, no Angular app.